# Is there "another" way of getting log information on SFTP activity?

Tags: mysql, debian, mariadb, phpmyadmin, moodle

I'm administrating a debian server since last week. It used to have another administrator.

I presume it's been hacked: files might have been read via SFTP to obtain information about a site that's hosted on the server I'm mentioning, and then tables were deleted from the database via PhpMyAdmin.

I'm about to give up here, since phpmyadmin doesn't log activity by default, and SFTP doesn't either. The server's SFTP activity and phpmyadmin were not configured to output data to log files.

The plausible "hacker" made the mistake of accessing the server with a user I didn't realize existed, a couple of times via SSH! however I couldn't track any more activity, since he/she was careful enough to only navigate to the folder where the site is hosted (directly, not even messing around through the files, so he clearly knew the server) the rest of the activity was made through phpmyadmin and SFTP.

Not many people knew about this user on the server as you are probably realizing, since it was NOT root, and I've got his IP address which we all know won't help much.

All he/she did on the server, when logged as the other user, was `cd` to the directory where the site lives, made a directory there called "m" and that's it; the "m" directory was removed, it wasn't removed using the terminal by me, nor by the intruder.

The file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` is now configured to track activity, and works, but it's of course a little too late, unfortunately.

Can you please help me find a way of tracking the SFTP activity or any other way of tracking the activity of a particular server's user other than executing the `history` command logging in as that user via SSH? THANKS!

Comment: Build a time machine, then go back in time and enable auditing and the various logs on the server before the break-in.

Comment: @MichaelHampton how's that useful?

Comment: You're asking for the impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Couldn't track SFTP activity.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find information about the SFTP activity, prior to the changes that were made after the attacks. However, apache logs were very useful here, and as local internet providers don't change public IPs so often, we were able to determine that the missing tables I mentioned, were made by the same IP address, and we also know the device that was used to perform the queries.

## But we didn't even need to build a time machine after all...

Anyone dealing with a similar situation might check the apache logs and find out crucial information in how/when malicious activity took place, and have an idea of who did it.